# Podio API: How to get IDs of ALL organisation workspaces (both open and private)

Tags: podio

I want to get all workspace IDs for a given organisation in Podio. This means both open and private workspaces. Any API authentication is ok. Workspaces included should be the same as on the list an organisation admin can access in Podio UI via Organisation Settings > Workspaces.

What I've tried so far:

I have 132 workspaces showing up in Organisation Settings > Workspaces.

[Get list of organisation workspaces](https://developers.podio.com/doc/spaces/get-list-of-organization-workspaces-238875316) gives 104 of them

There are 26 workspaces the user doesn't have access to (indicated by "request access" in Settings > Workspaces).

There's one workspace the user can gain access to (as listed by [Get available spaces](https://developers.podio.com/doc/spaces/get-available-spaces-1911961))

That leaves one workspace unaccounted for (132 - 104 - 26 - 1 = 1).
And it also doesn't give all workspace IDs.

[Get all spaces on organisation](https://developers.podio.com/doc/organizations/get-all-spaces-on-organization-11902608) returns only 99 workspaces.

Any ideas?

Comment: To get workspace information, you are using user authentication, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: With user authentication you will only get what user have access to, so if a user don't have access to a workspace, even if he is an admin in the organization he won't get details about the workspace under the organization.

Comment: I believe the API should still return *some* information on all workspaces under the organisation – even if workspace name is not returned. Both Podio UI (organisation settings > Workspaces) and API documentation (https://developers.podio.com/doc/organizations/get-all-spaces-on-organization-11902608) would seem to support this assumption.